# Access(R/W) to Git repository with Facebook, Twitter, or Google Account?

Tags: facebook, git, authentication, twitter, oauth

I don't know much about managing or setting git server,

but is it possible to authenticate the users with Facebook, Twitter, or Google account
to **push** or pull the repository?

I am thinking of service that random user (with basic information like e-mail, or OAuth token maybe?) can contribute the repository. Do you have any idea?